# Registry Access not allowed in remote editing with powershell (also as admin)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to deploy a registry value to disable speakers inside a 40-machine lab. From specs, I must look for a regvar on a tree, go back to the parent key and change a `DeviceState` regvalue to `0x10000001`.

Below a snippets, as I found on the Internet. I just tried using .Net objects with the same issues.

```cs
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\" -Recurse | % {
    if ((Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match "Realtek High Definition Audio") {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSParentPath -Name "DeviceState" -Value 268435457
    }
}
```

Although I can modify the same regvar by accessing through regedit, The script output

> Access to the registry not allowed

(Yes, I run it as admin).
Any Idea?

Comment: Did you check that admins actually do have write access to that key?

Comment: Yes.Indeed "None" seems to have writing permissions (exept than "TrustedInstaller"). Maybe this is the real question: "why no one can write, but i can through regedit, cannot through ps?"

Comment: did you try `Set-ItemProperty  -Force …`?

Comment: Yes, I did. This morning I tried an "uncomfortable" workaround (not an answer, actually). after getting the right path, the script composes an "ad hoc" .reg file and launches regedit with the  usual invoke-espression,...Quite "barbarian", but it works